# NVIDIA card fan spins faster when not in use

Tags: nvidia

In my system I have an NVIDIA video card (GeForce 450 GTS) as an extra card (video output via motherboard ATI) for bitcoin mining.

If I start mining, the fan speeds up a little, but the weird thing is, if I stop mining the fan starts to spin much much faster (generating lots of noise). And it doesn't stop doing that.

What could be the cause? And how can I fix that?

Comment: How precisely do you stop mining?